# Is there a difftime() version vectors?

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, difference

I have datetime vectors with quite different entries. Sometimes the intervall between the entries is only some seconds and somtimes days. Like that:

```
# Vector increasing by seconds
time1 <- ymd_hms(c("2023-05-02 14:15:00", "2023-05-02 14:15:01", "2023-05-02 14:15:02"))
# Vector increasing by days
time2 <- ymd_hms(c("2023-05-02 14:15:00", "2023-05-03 14:15:00", "2023-05-04 14:15:00"))
```

I need to know time differences for all vectors. The problem with `diff()` is that it automatically chooses a time unit and we can not set an own unit (no `unit` argument):

```
diff(time1) == diff(time2)
# TRUE
```

Fortunately, the `difftime()` function has an `unit` argument. But the problem with `difftime` is that it does not accept vectors:

```
difftime(time1)
# Error in difftime(time1) : argument "time2" is missing, with no default
```

Is there a function that calculates differences for a whole vector where we can set the unit? I guess there are more elegant methods than `sapply(seq(1, length(time1)-1, 1), function(i){difftime(time1[i+1], time1[i], units= "sec")})`?

Comment: You could just do something like `na.omit(difftime(time1, lag(time1)))`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Using this I get `Time differences in secs [1] 0 0 0` which is not what expect.

Comment: I get `1 1` in seconds for `time1` and `1 1` in days doing the same thing with `time2`. I have the `tidyverse` loaded, so it will be using `dplyr::lag`, rather than the base version.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Yes, that was the problem. Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, the `as.numeric` function accepts a `units =`  argument that you can use with `diff()` that provides flexibility in the output:

```
# time 1, in seconds
as.numeric(diff(time1), units = "secs")
# [1] 1 1
as.numeric(diff(time1), units = "days")
# [1] 1.157407e-05 1.157407e-05

# time 2, in days
as.numeric(diff(time2), units = "days")
# [1] 1 1
as.numeric(diff(time2), units = "secs")
# [1] 86400 86400
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want even more flexibility, you could use my function `time_diff()` which uses `lubridate` to support period time differences as well as the usual duration differences.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tdiff <- function(x, n = 1, ...){
  out <- time_diff(dplyr::lag(x, n = n), x, ...)
  tail(out, n = -n)
}

tdiff(time1, by = "sec", n = 1)
#> [1] 1 1
# Period or duration differences
tdiff(time1, by = "month", type = "period")
#> [1] 3.733572e-07 3.733572e-07
tdiff(time1, by = "month", type = "duration")
#> [1] 3.802571e-07 3.802571e-07
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the difftime() function with vectors by specifying both the time1 and time2 arguments as vectors of the same length. To calculate time differences with a specific unit, you can set the units argument to the desired unit.